# Windows 8 UEFI installation won't start

Tags: installation, windows-8, uefi

I am trying to install Windows 8 on my laptop using UEFI instead of BIOS.
So far I have gotten myself a Windows 8 installation DVD and a bootable USB which both work perfect with the normal installation option.

However, once I go to boot options and choose the UEFI USB or DVD (Which didn't always showed up for me but eventually did.) does the Windows 8 installer starts and never continues. See [this](http://sdrv.ms/ThxVz9) screenshot to see what I mean.

I have tried with a second USB to launch the installation using the EFI Shell but this returns the same problem. Also have I searched on the web for solutions but got no result.

My laptop is an Asus K53SC. The BIOS version is the latest found on the product page (version 216).

Comment: Does your laptop actually have a UEFI BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Format the USB flash drive as FAT32.

Then use [RMPrepUSB](http://www.rmprepusb.com/) to make the FAT32 USB flash drive bootable to use it to install Windows 8. AFAIK, only RMPrepUSB supports FAT32 and all other (Microsoft USB/DVD Download Tool/Rufus/etc.) support only NTFS.

Comment: The USB is formatted to FAT32 and converted to GPT already. Yet it still doesn't work.
However, on a forum did someone said I should wipe my whole hard drive including all the partitions. I'm going to try this as soon as I'm back home.

Comment: Try http://www.rmprepusb.com/

Comment: Will do ;) Will tell the results once done

Answer (score 1):

I found that, by default, the Windows 8 Upgrade ISO does not have UEFI support.  Try checking out this link that describes how to add UEFI support to your ISO and create media that will be properly recognized by your firmware as having UEFI support.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/is-anyone-else-having-problems-with-uefi-support/a8e39541-941e-498d-9b23-134a9f9ada87